# convergence of entropy and sigma-fields

Tags: probability, ergodic-theory, entropy

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266695/question-about-entropy).
Let $(X_1, X_2, \ldots)$ be a sequence of random variables such that each $X_n$ takes its values in a finite space, say $\{0,1\}$, and the $\sigma$-field $\sigma(X_1, X_2, \ldots)$ is discrete (generated by a denumerable partition of events). The maximal possible entropy of $(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is $n \log 2$. Is it possible that $\frac{H(X_1, \ldots, X_n)}{n}$ does not go to zero as $n\to \infty$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is impossible.  Fix any $\epsilon>0$.  Then, since, by assumption, the space is discrete, there is some finite set $\cal A$ of sequences $(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ such that ${\Bbb P}((X_i)\in {\cal A})>1-\epsilon$.  Let $A$ be the event $(X_i)\in{\cal A}$.  Then
\begin{eqnarray*}
H(X_1,\dots,X_n)&\le&
H(X_1,\dots,X_n,A)\\
&=& H(A)+H(X_1,\ldots,X_n\mid A){\Bbb P}(A)+H(X_1,\ldots,X_n\mid A^C)(1-{\Bbb P}(A))\\
&\le& H(A)+H((X_i)\mid A)+n\epsilon\log 2.
\end{eqnarray*}
Since $\cal A$ is finite, $H((X_i)\mid A)$ is finite, so
$$
\limsup_n \frac{H(X_1,\ldots,X_n)}{n}\le \epsilon \log 2,
$$
and letting $\epsilon\to 0$, 
$$
\lim_n \frac{H(X_1,\ldots,X_n)}{n}=0.
$$

Comment: Great. I need to learn these basic formulas about conditional entropy but I believe you.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your solution David, using the wikipedia page about conditional entropy. You denote by $H(A)$ the entropy of the indicator function of $A$, don't you ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Similarly, $H(X_1,\ldots,X_n,A)$ is the joint entropy of the $X_i$s and the indicator function of $A$.